# Populating a DropDownList in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a little problem in populating a drop down list in MVC3. I hope there would be somebody to give me a help on this.

I am trying to render a View of Users which contains a DropDownList for Cities. This should be fetched from the Database. In fact, The User class has a ForeignKey of the City class.

Here are the Controller and the View:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    //return View(model);
    var DefaultCities = new[]
    {
        new {Name = "London"}
    }.ToList();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cities = unitOfWork.CityRepository.Get() as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
    ViewData["AllCities"] = cities != null ? new SelectList(cities.AsEnumerable(), "CityID", "Name") : new SelectList(DefaultCities.AsEnumerable(), "Name");

    return View(unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(orderBy: us => us.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID)).OfType<User>().ToList());
}
```

//The View

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList(**"CityID"**, ViewData["AllCities"] as SelectList, "--Choose One--"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID)
</div>
```

But the following error displays:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CityID'.

This is my first time on MVC! What does the 'CityID' refer to? What should I write as the first argument of `@Html.DropDownList`?

As I have read on different articles, the argument mentioned should be the name of the form field.

Can anyone suggest a sample code?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The following line of code is wrong:

```
new SelectList(cities.AsEnumerable(), "CityID", "Name")
```

You are specifying `CityID` and `Name` properties but `cities` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. And `SelectListItem` only has `Value` and `Text` properties. There's no such thing as `CityID` and `Name`.

So you probably meant:

```
ViewData["AllCities"] = cities != null 
    ? new SelectList(cities, "Value", "Text") 
    : new SelectList(DefaultCities, "Name");
```

or simply:

```
ViewData["AllCities"] = cities != null 
    ? cities 
    : new SelectList(DefaultCities, "Name");
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList( 
    "CityID", 
    ViewData["AllCities"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
    "--Choose One--"
)
```

As far as the `CityID` argument in your view is concerned, this will basically be used by the DropDownList helper to generate the `name` property of the select element in your DOM and as a consequence that will be the selected value name being passed to the controller action that you are submitting your form to.

By the way using ViewData/ViewBag is very bad practice. I would recommend you using a view model instead and have a strongly typed DropDownListFor helper in your view which will be tied to a specific property on your view model.

Comment: If you use my first code snippet in the controller you could keep the same code in the view as you currently have. And if you use my second code snippet you need to update the DropDownList helper call in your view as shown in my answer in order to use an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: I'm wondering how the error still appears. I have done exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: If the error still appears I guess you didn't use the code shown in my answer. Also you haven't specified when this error occurs? On rendering the form initially ot after you submit this form? If it is on submitting this form to some `[HttpPost]` controller action did you make sure to populate this `ViewData["AllCities"]` field the same way you did in your GET action if you redisplay the same view?

Comment: Let me tell you something that the User class is a derived one from the ManBase class. This is the latter which contains the CityID. Could it be the cause of the error? Since the name should be the nome of the form field!

Comment: Yeah, that might be. Unfortunately since you are not following best practices of using a view model but are instead mixing some domain models with ViewData, it is very hard to diagnose the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: The scenario is like this; I got the Home page, then I click the User Panel, Next I enter the panel but as I click the Create New User link, the error occurs!!

Comment: Ok.. by this way I better to do the good job which is ViewModel.. If you know any Helpful link, I would appreciate if you share it.. Otherwise, I would find some.

Answer (score 1):

Im curious how the output of your cities repository casts to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`
But assuming its a enumeration of city objects you can try the following

In your controller

```
ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(unitOfWork.CityRepository.Get(), "CityID", "Name");
```

In your view

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CityID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Cities)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at your code, if the cities are null then it goes to your Default Cities.  However, you've only listed a Name and not a CityID in the default SelectList.

**You may also want to just try to bind the default collection first to make sure it works.  Then try the other... just some debugging tips to narrow it down.**

Here's what you need:

```
var cities = unitOfWork.CityRepository.Get();

    ViewData["AllCities"] = cities != null ? new SelectList(cities, "CityID", "Name") : new SelectList(DefaultCities.AsEnumerable(), "CityID", "Name");
```

And you view would be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Cities",(SelectList)ViewData["AllCities"])
```

Also, I just saw where you are defining DefaultCities.  It doesn't have a CityID either.
**This:**

```
var DefaultCities = new[]
    {
        new {Name = "London"}
    }.ToList();
```

**Should be this:**

```
var DefaultCities = new[]
    {
        new {Name = "London", CityID=1}
    }.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks my friend but unfortunately it didn't work. :( I guess the problem is something else. Actually, the User class is derived from the Man class and the CityID is the latter's property. So do you think it might be the cause?

Comment: Does the your City class have properties of CityID and Name?  Check the case also. I'm looking at one right now following the same pattern that works fine.  What error are you getting?  That would be helpful.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, just a matter of time difference. Actually, yes the City class exactly involves properties, CityID and Name. The scenario is as such; I got the Home page, then I click the User Panel, So I enter the panel but as I click the Create New User link, the error occurs!! "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CityID'."

Comment: Ooh.. My God.. I've made an awful mistake! I don't like to mention it but it was just a matter of lack of attention :( Now It works fine! Thanks you... ;)